# How to use struct in a static library

Tags: c++, static-libraries

Hy! I want to create a library and for my functions I need to create a struct

```
struct elem{
    int inf;
    elem* adr;
};
```

but when I'm building this it shows me just

> error: unknown type name 'elem'

How can I declare it correct?

Comment: Are you working in C or in C++?

Comment: [Reproduce I cannot](http://ideone.com/N1fLxy). Valid C++ this. Correct I believe @MatteoItalia 's suspicion is.

Comment: Have you checked out on which line the error occurs?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you compile as C, not C++. It could be because of "extern C" pragma used above the definition. If you change "elem *adr" to "struct elem* adr" and it works then my suspicion is correct